# ¿Como crear una imagen por cada video en un input multiple?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estoy creando una herramienta para que los usuarios puedan subir videos, pero pueden subir hasta cinco videos, estoy utilizando canvas con javascript para que me cree un thumbnail por cada video subido, cuando un usuario sube un video no hay problema, pero cuando sube mas de uno, me repite la misma imagen del primer video para todos los demás, no he podido hacer que me cree la imagen correspondiente para cada video.

Este es el codigo javascript:

```js
$(".guardarVideo").click(function(e){

var cantidadVideos = document.getElementById('fileVideos').files.length;

for (var x = 0; x < cantidadVideos; x++) {

    var file = document.getElementById('fileVideos').files[x];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
    var blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: file.type});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    var timeupdate = function() {
      if (snapImage()) {
        video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
        video.pause();
      }
    };
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
      if (snapImage()) {
        video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
      }
    });
    var snapImage = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var arrText = new Array();
      var image = canvas.toDataURL();
      var success = image.length > 100000;

      if (success) {



        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = image;
        document.getElementById('info').appendChild(img);



        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        
        }
        return success;
      };
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
      video.preload = 'metadata';
      video.src = url;
      // Load video in Safari / IE11
      video.muted = true;
      video.playsInline = true;
      video.play();

    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    }
    });
```

```html
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" name="files[]" class="custom-file-input" id="fileVideos" lang="es" multiple>
<label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Solo puedes subir videos .mp4</label>
</div>
                                 
<div id="info"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn video btn-primary btn-block guardarVideo"><h1>Publicar</h1></button>
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar la declaración de todas las variables, en lugar de `var nombreDeVariable` usa `let nombreDeVariable` y lee acerca de [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). En resumen, `var` crea variables globales y, estando dentro de un ciclo, se actualizan en cada iteración, mientras que con `let` se crea una nueva variable "independiente" por cada iteración.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby tienes toda la razón, ya funciono, ya me muestra la imagen de cada video, ya tenia dos días con el problema y no encontraba nada en internet.